# How to create a key as folder and value as files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

- I have a bucket name testfolder
- Inside testfolder there are test1,test2,test3
- Each folder have there are csv files
- Need to create a key value pair for folder and files

Expected out

output1   `{ 'test1':['csv1.csv'], 'test2':['csv2'], 'test3':['csv3']}`

output2   `{ 'test1':'csv1.csv', 'test2':'csv2', 'test3':'csv3'}`

```
#list all the objects
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
final_data = {}
all_objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket = 'testfolder') 
#List the object in subfolder
#create a dictionary
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain better??

Comment: @RiccardoBucco simple i need to create on dictionary with folder as key and files as values

Comment: It sounds like you want to split the S3 key at the last "/"? Perhaps it would help if you showed the _exact_ file structure in your bucket rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: @Parsifal  testfolder/test1,testfolder/test2,testfolder/test3 are the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following code which gives `output1` format. For `output2` you can modify the `final_data` accordingly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

final_data = defaultdict(list)

in_bucket = 'test-bucket-folder-4412313'

for obj in s3.Bucket(in_bucket).objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
    
    folder_name = obj.key.split('/')[0]
    file_name = obj.key.split('/')[1]

    final_data[folder_name].append(file_name)


print(dict(final_data))
```

It prints out:

```
{'test1': ['csv1.csv'], 'test2': ['csv2.csv'], 'test3': ['csv3.csv']}
```